# How can I see the network up/down speed for each tab in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, monitoring

Where can I see the network up/down speed for each tab in Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate?

The Resource Monitor doesn't distinguish between tabs:

[image]

The Google Chrome's Task Manager doesn't distinguish between up (send) and down (receiving):

[image]

I can use the PIDs displayed in the Google Chrome's Task Manager, and then look at   the Network Activity in Windows's Resource Monitor:

[image]

Is there any more convenient way? I.e., I would prefer to be Network Activity  to display the tab name instead of the PID.

Comment: The only way this could work is as a Chrome Extension as you'd have to measure the up/download speed for each tab within the browser.

Comment: You can use DU Meter (dumeter.com) to measure overall network traffic and by process as well, but not by tab.

Answer (score 1):

A search of [Chrome's Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) did not reveal any extension which would track the up/down speed of each process by the tab it's tied to, much less show ihat speed. However, if your concern is to find what's slowing you down, [here's an article](https://www.businessinsider.com/google-chrome-tabs-extensions-slowing-down-your-computer-2018-6) which offers a method to find what's slowing your PC down.